# Синонимизировать [jpeg] и [jpg]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Сейчас обнаружил две идентичные малоиспользуемые метки [jpeg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpeg) и [jpg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpg). Предлагаю их синонимизировать. Основной оставить [jpeg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpeg)

Comment: В какую сторону? К таким вопросам надо публиковать ответ с предлагаемым решением. Ну или хотя бы просто точнее предлагать.

Comment: @Qwertiy Поточнее предложил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, у меня jpeg ассоциируется с алгоритмом сжатия, а jpg с форматом файла.
Но, похоже, используют их как попало, так что синонимизировал.

Comment: синонимизатор всея русо

Comment: Драйвера добить не желаете?