# Синонимизировать метки [bat] и [cmd]

Tags: обсуждение, метки, синонимы-меток

Метки [bat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bat) и [cmd](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd) описывают одно и то же понятие и зачастую используются совместо

Comment: "описывают одно и то же понятие" - строго говоря, нет. Cmd - командный интерпретатор в windows (программа) и расширение для его сценариев. Bat - расширение для пакетных файлов в DOS и Windows. Но да, применительно к SO, они почти всегда используются для одного и того же. (Хотя на английском SO не синонимизированы.)

Comment: Вот (здесь)[https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6995/221228] была подобная проблема. Я предлагаю все же исходить из практики вопросов. Либо нужно настолько радикально изменить описания этих меток, чтобы не возникало вопросов о том, когда что использовать. Лично я, из вашего комментария, разницы так и не понял

Comment: Текущие описания меток абсолютно четко раскрывают оба понятия. Это, разумеется, не помогает, так как их никто не читает. Синонимизировать может и нужно, но сначала нужно изучить содержимое обеих меток и посмотреть, что выбивается из общей тематики (есть ли вопросы про батники в DOS? есть ли вопросы по cmd, не относящиеся к батникам?)

Comment: Если исходить из практики вопросов, то да, это для многих синоним. Но синомизировав эти метки мы будем потакать этой массовой "безграмотности". Если очень абстрагироваться, то cmd - "чем сделать", bat - "что сделать".

Answer (score 4):

Нет, так как данные метки означают разные понятия, хоть они и родственны. Если я использую утилиту cmd, то это вообще не значит, что я имею ввиду bat-файлы. В целом, как я вижу получается (могу ошибаться), что [cmd](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd) — более широкое понятие. Поэтому если мы сделаем основной метку [bat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bat), то это будет нонсенс (как намного более узкое понятие). Если наоборот, то потеряем специфику вопроса, если он про написание bat-скриптов.

Answer (score -1):

Сделать основной метку [bat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bat)

Answer (score -1):

Сделать основной метку [cmd](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd)