# Исчезают голоса с ответов на мете

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, ответы, голоса-против, мета

Я уже несколько раз голосовал против ответов: [раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7055/220571) и [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7054/220571). В первый раз, когда повторял голосование, думал, может показалось, но когда голоса уже пропали на третий раз, я понимаю, что это явный дефект. Кстати, там было ещё много других голосов на этих ответах, но сейчас они почему-то девственно чисты, как будто никто и не голосовал.

Я не знаю, насколько большой масштаб данной проблемы и это охватывает ли она также другие посты, основой сайт и другие сайты сети StackExchange.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75584/discussion-on-question-by-vadim-ovchinnikov------).

Comment: @Qwertiy Да можно уже вообще все комменты снести, они уже неактуальны.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предположу, что ты голосовал не только против двух этих ответов, но и против самого вопроса. 3 голоса против одного участника (как минимум, сделанные за короткое время) автоматически откатываются как серийное голосование. Советую поставить 2 голоса за ответы в один день, а на следующий добавить минус на вопрос. Ну или наоборот.

PS: А вот 3 плюса не откатываются.

Answer (score 5):

Голоса откатила система, признав их «подозрительными». Возможно, вы голосуете слишком одинаково или слишком быстро или еще как–то так, как обычно не голосуют. Во временной шкале я вижу комментарий к действию:

> «признано недействительным автоматически».

Comment: на Мете другие правила по голосованию. Что "подозрительного" в том что человек минусы поставил нескольким вариантам в вопросе-опроснике?

Comment: @jfs правила другие идеологически, но запрограммировано поведение одинаково. С этим надо что-то делать, но никто ж не будет.

Comment: @alexolut: из данного ответа у меня не создалось впечатление, что поведение системы нежелательно. Сперва нужно договориться, что хотим, а потом уже как это исправить. К примеру, "общие" ответы подпадают под автоматический откат? И полезны ли вообще ленивые-опросники с ответами где участник без попытки обоснования тупо варианты приводит (не стоит время тратить, чтобы поддерживать такие опросы). Можно договориться (в faq прописать по необходимости), чтобы варианты для опросников писались бы разными людьми, которые поддерживают вариант, который они описывают (чтобы не было формальных отписок).

Comment: @jfs, оно и есть нежелательно. Было несколько предложений, но что-то они игнорируются, как всегда.

Comment: @Qwertiy Подскажите, пожалуйста, про что именно вы говорите?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, было минимум 3 предложения на эту тему, но не могу найти: 1. Не использовать автооткаты голосов на мете. 2. То же, но только при наличии метки [meta-tag:голосование]. 3. Как минимум для меты считать для отката не число голосов, а число вопросов, в рамках которых они поставлены (если под одним вопросом 5 ответов одного участника, то голоса на них считаются за 1, а не за 5).

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, в этом нет никакого криминала или дефекта.

Мне иногда приходилось видеть, что при нестабильной связи появляется уведомление, что не удалось сохранить голос на вопросе/ответе - и я понимаю, что сохранение данных проверяется, а не оставлено на самотёк.

С другой стороны, насколько я знаю, у модераторов есть инструменты обнуления голосования - и вполне возможно, что в некоторых случаях такое вмешательство имело место. Возможно, этот момент лучше уточнить у Николаса или модераторов, есть ли подобные права или я что-то напутал. Ну и если да, то можно попросить посмотреть, не было ли именно с этими вопросами каких-либо действий. (Сомневаюсь, но всё же)

И с третьей стороны, система действительно может откатывать некоторые голоса, в случае каких-то накруток.

В общем, сценариев много - не думаю, что имеет место баг. Я лично ни разу не сталкивался с подобными штуками, хотя я один из постоянных участников голосования.